# how to trust self signed CA root cert in MAUI apps for android?

Tags: android, ssl, maui

I followed this tutorial to generate my own SSL cert (URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlcrTSvMioU ) for use with Windows and Linux. And they work fine. I created a .net 6 web api app and used the self signed cert, the browser is able to access the restful service without warning.

Now, using a MAUI app, I tried to access the same service and it gave exception and can't access. On Windows and Linux, I have to trust the root CA cert that I used to sign the SSL certs with. Now, how do I do it for Android? What is the best practice for this?
Could someone please enlighten me on this?